# Install spotify-client on Ubuntu using puppet via Apt module

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, spotify, apt

What puppet code do I need to install the spotify-client on Ubuntu using puppet's Apt module?

The [spotify installation instructions](https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/download/linux/) are:

> 1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages 
>      `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver
>      hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys
>      BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886`
> 2. Add the Spotify repository `echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`
> 3. Update list of available packages `sudo apt-get update`
> 4. Install Spotify `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

To add a repository (Step 1), [Puppet's Apt module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt#add-gpg-keys) says to do this:

```
apt::key { 'spotify':
    id      => 'BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886',
    server  => 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80',
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to do step 2, and add the repository.  How do I translate this: `echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` into my puppet manifest using Apt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the apt module to create the apt source files, rather than having to manage them manually as files.

Something like this should work:

```
apt::key { 'spotify':
  id      => 'BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886',
  server  => 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80',
}
->
apt::source {'spotify':
  location => "http://repository.spotify.com",
  release => "stable",
  repos => "non-free",
}
->
package {'spotify-client':
  ensure => "installed",
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I notice that the key parameters can be included right within the apt::source as well.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages**

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886

**2. Add the Spotify repository**

echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

**3. Add this line to your /etc/apt/sources.list file:**

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main

**4.Run**

sudo apt-get update

**5.- Run**

apt-get install libssl1.0.0

**6.- Run**

sudo apt-get install spotify-client